# Units of real world seems to be scaled in OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, camera, camera-calibration

I'm trying to setup stereo rectification. I'm using just one camera which rotates by small steps around the object. But I'm confused. The object I'm trying to snap has sizes about ~3-4cm. The radius of rotations is about 6 cm. But when I rectify I have got finite values of xyz-matrix each of them has length from camera about 300-2000 units. Why? How to get position/rotation of the second camera (the second position of the camera) in the first reference frame?

```
org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.stereoRectify(mCameraMatrix, mDistortionCoefficients, 
mCameraMatrix, mDistortionCoefficients, dispFloat.size(), R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q);
org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.reprojectImageTo3D(dispFloat,xyz,Q);
```

The values of matrices are (pseudocode):

```
Input:
mCameraMatrix:
|1076.080810546875f,0.0f,639.5f|
        |0.0f,1076.080810546875f, 359.5f|
        |0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,|
mDistortionCoefficients:
| 0.11665083467960358f,-0.15972141921520233f,0.0f,0.0f,-0.29710251092910767f|

R:
|[0.965926,0,0.258819]|
|[0,1,0]|
|[-0.258819,0,0.965926]|

 T:
|[1.55291,0,0.204445]|

output:
R1:
|0.9965080795455151,        -0.0733390286815368,        0.039912833431844846|
|0.08349638947769386,       0.8751762387100398,     -0.47654475565421633|
|1.8566063818213976E-5,     0.4782132767598534,     0.8782437370035183|
R2:
| 1.0,      0,      0|
|0,     0.8784559480840216,     0.4778233431675381|
|0,     -0.47782334316753805,       0.8784559480840215|
P1:
|538.0404052734375,     0.0,        756.766210841568,       0.0|
|0.0,       538.0404052734375,      428.56917572021484,     0.0|
|0.0,       0.0,        1.0,        0.0|
P2:
|538.0404052734375,     0.0,        756.766210841568,       |-281.3598668991448
|0.0,       538.0404052734375,      428.56917572021484,     0.0|
|0.0,       0.0,        1.0,        0.0|
Q:
|1.0,       0.0,        0.0,        -756.766210841568|
| 0.0,      1.0,        0.0,        -428.56917572021484|
|0.0,       0.0,        0.0,        538.0404052734375|
|0.0,       0.0,        1.9122855409449757,     -0.0|
```

As I understood, the values so huge due to mCameraMatrix[0][0] and mCameraMatrix[1][1] have values about ~1000. How to recalculate to real size? How to get the second camera position of in the reference frame of the first position?

Comment: how did you compute the camera matrix? afaik automatic methods have some ambiguity concerning the scale.

Comment: I'm using an example of OpenCV project and this image: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/doc/acircles_pattern.png

Comment: @Micka I'm using directly this project: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/camera-calibration